# siunitx, exponent-color & hectare - ar

Tags: color, siunitx, convert

i am creating a bunch of tasks for my pupils and I use siunitx.

I want them to convert units.

There are three problems:

1. i want to predefine the unit they shall convert to, so I thought I use the SI command and make the number white, but the exponent also is set to white
2. with the Exponent-to-prefix option siunitx does not use units like hectare or ar, how can I change this.
3. if i give a number and siunitx converts it, it does not cut off unneccessary zeros.

thank you very much, kind regards

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\def\mm{-6}
\def\cm{-4}
\def\dm{-2}
\def\m{0}
\def\ar{2}
\def\ha{4}
\def\km{6}

\newcommand{\umwandlungb}[3]{
\SI[scientific-notation=fixed,exponent-to-prefix,fixed-exponent=#1]{#2}{\meter\squared}\;
(\SI[scientific-notation=fixed,exponent-to-prefix,fixed-exponent=#3,color=white, unit-color=black]{#2}{\square\meter})
=
\SI[scientific-notation=fixed,exponent-to-prefix,fixed-exponent=#3]{#2}{\meter\squared}
}

\begin{document}

\umwandlungb{\ha}{3600}{\dm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\mm`  or `\def\m{0}` etc. seriously? Your `\umwandlungb` macro has spurious spaces as well...

Comment: hi, yes I'm serious with that. If there is a better way to tell siunitx to which unit it shall convert I would be happy to hear about. The macro works this way, I didn't have any problems with spaces.

Comment: I hate to seem advertising my own projects, but I have coded a question generator similar to what you want to do here. Find `units4school` on github